# Catching an error that I dont want to catch

Tags: java, exception, rethrow

Everytime I run this code, everything works fine, but if deposit methods throws an error,
only the `catch` in the main method catches the exception and prints the string, despite the  `catch` in the `ExceptionsDemo`. Why does that happen?

```
    public class ExceptionsDemo {
    public static void show() throws IOException {
        var account = new Account();
        try {
            account.deposit(0);//this method might throw an IOException
            account.withDraw(2);
        } catch (InsufficientFundsException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                ExceptionsDemo.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An unexpected error occurred");
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because in your `show()` method, you are catching a specific type of exception called `InsufficientFundsException`. But the exception thrown by `account.deposit()` is `IOException` which is caught only in your main method. That is why the catch in the main method gets executed and not the catch in ExcpetionsDemo

If you want to catch IOException in your ExceptionsDemo class you can do this:

```
public static void show() {
    var account = new Account();
    try {
        account.deposit(0);//this method might throw an IOException
        account.withDraw(2);
    } catch (InsufficientFundsException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

A single try block can have multiple catch blocks for each type of exception and the handling of each exception can be customized to what you want by coding it in each of their catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your ExceptionsDemo throws a `IOException`, your `catch` in `ExceptionsDemo` **only** catches a `InsufficientFundsException` so it will not be caught in the `ExceptionsDemo`, it will bubble to the caller, and be caught there, providing there is a `catch` block to handle said exception, which it does, otherwise you'll have an *uncaught* exception.  It's not been rethrown from `ExceptionsDemo`, because its not being caught in the first place

Answer (score -1):

```java
try {
    // do what you want
} catch (InsufficientFundsException e) {
    // catch what you want
} catch (Exception e) {
    // catch unexpected errors, if you want (optional)
}
```